# How do i get multiple jquery selectables in tabs working

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-selectable

I have two tabs made with jquery which contains seperate selectables.
The tab that opens by default, the selectable works fine.
When going to the other tab, selecting using the lasso won't work.
Problems started when added the stop event to the selectable.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#div1" id="tab1">Div 1 (0)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2" id="tab2">Div 2 (0)</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="div1">
    <ul class="selectable" id="sel1">
      <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">13</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">14</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">15</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <ul class="selectable" id="sel2">
        <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">13</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">14</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">15</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
$("#sel1").selectable( {
    autoRefresh: false,
    stop: function() {
        var count = 0;
        $( '.ui-selected', this).each(function() {
            count++;
        });
        $('#tab1').html('Div 1 (' + count + ')');
    }
});
$("#sel2").selectable( {
    autoRefresh: false,
    stop: function() {
        var count = 0;
        $( '.ui-selected', this).each(function() {
            count++;
        });
        $('#tab2').html('Div 2 (' + count + ')');
    }
});
$("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/3pKQf/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
 autoRefresh: true,
```

on the second one